# I am getting List out of bound error in my test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

```
@istest

private class StudenthandlerTestClass {

  /* @testSetup
   static void testData()
   {

        list<department__c> deptlist = new list<department__c>();
        for(integer i=1;i<4;i++){
        Department__c  newdept = new department__c();   
        newdept.name='dept'+i;
        newdept.no_of_students__c=0;  
        deptlist.add(newdept);
        }
      insert deptlist;
   } */



    @istest
    static void validateinsert() {

      list<department__c> deptlist = new list<department__c>();
        for(integer i=1;i<4;i++){
        Department__c  newdept = new department__c();   
        newdept.name='dept'+i;
        newdept.no_of_students__c=0;  
        deptlist.add(newdept);
        }
      insert deptlist;



      //deptlist = [SELECT Id, no_of_students__c FROM Department__c];

      list<student_details__c> studlist = new list<student_details__c>();  

       for(integer i=1;i<4;i++){
       student_details__c newstudent = new Student_details__c();
       newstudent.Name='Student'+i;   
       newstudent.department__c = deptlist[i].id;    
       studlist.add(newstudent);
      }

       insert studlist;



        deptlist = [SELECT Id,name, no_of_students__c FROM Department__c];  

    //    for(integer i=1;i<4;i++){

       System.assertEquals('dept1' , deptlist[1].name);
       System.assertEquals(1 , deptlist[1].no_of_students__c);
      //  }
    }
}
```

the error line shown is "**newstudent.department__c = deptlist[i].id;**"

Am I not assigning the student with the department correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index in arrays and lists starts from zero 0. change your loops to (considering fact, that your original loop has 3 iterations):

```
for(integer i=0;i<3;i++){
    Department__c  newdept = new department__c();   
    newdept.name='dept'+i;
    newdept.no_of_students__c=0;  
    deptlist.add(newdept);
}
```

Comment: Oops,oh my, that was really a bad one from my side. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

List index always start with zero. 
make change in code

> **newstudent.department__c = deptlist[i-1].id;**